Streaming bash command output into cURL
Hi I'm running a bash command that streams output data that looks like this:
nats sub demo.1 --queue demo -r | jq
{
  "count": "8",
  "time": "2024-05-15T12:51:41+01:00",
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsIm....",
  "name": "abc"
}
{
  "count": "10",
  "time": "2024-05-15T12:51:42+01:00",
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsIm....",
  "name": "abc"
}
{
  "count": "11",
  "time": "2024-05-15T12:51:42+01:00",
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsIm....",
  "name": "abc"
}

Note that each output block is a separate entity and I'm passing it into jq to essentially prettify it.
However, I need to pipe the output into a cURL command something like this like this.
curl 'https://localhost:8289/v1/certificatesigningrequest' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer jq.token" \
--data '{
    "input": jq.name,
}' -k -s 


I looked at using a while loop, but like this:
while [ nats sub demo.1 --queue demo -r ]
do
 curl ....
done

However, the command didn't seem to into the do loop.

Does this answer your question? Iterating through JSON array in Shell script

In short, --data @- will take the data to stream from standard input. jq itself should be constructing the {"input": ...} wrapper.

Sounds like you want something like:
while read -r token name; do
    curl 'https://localhost:8289/v1/certificatesigningrequest' \
        --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
        --data '{
            "input": '"$name"',
        }' -k -s 
done < <(nats sub demo.1 --queue demo -r | jq -j '.token," ",.name,"\n"' )

See towards the bottom of https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#Input_source_selection for why I'm using process substitution above instead of a pipe to loop on the output of nats | jq.

You might want to pre-encode the whole JSON data object with jq: read -r data … --data "$data" … <(nats … | jq -c '{input: .name}')

@pmf, could be, jq's not really my thing so I'm just trying to put the OPs code together in a way that should work if their code is right. Feel free to edit my answer or post your own if there's a better way.

So the structure of this works. But I need to use jq to get the values for the token and input name.
curl 'https://localhost:8289/v1/certificatesigningrequest' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer jq.token" \
--data '{
    "input": jq.name,
}' -k -s 
done < <(nats sub demo.1 --queue demo -r)


OK, I updated my answer with my best guess at what the jq syntax might be for extracting 2 fields so you can see how to read them in a loop to call curl, correct as necessary. I'm assuming that a "token" can't contain white space but a "name" might and that neither contain newlines.
